# VBA count statement adding values

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am working on an Excel sheet using VBA Macros.
I wish to add data to a database from the VBA code.

For one section I need to put comments in.

So I need:

1. comment
2. comment
3. comment
4. etc

The numbers basically needs to go up like 1,2,3,4.. for every comment that gets added

I've tried `(select Max(comment) AS count from HEADER)+1)` with not luck.

EDIT: there is a unique task number that goes up +1 in value per new task e.g.

TASKNO 1--COMMENT NO 1--COMMENT/TEST
TASKNO 2--COMMENT NO 1--COMMENT/TEST

TASKNO 3--COMMENT NO 1--COMMENT/TEST
TASKNO 3--COMMENT NO 2--COMMENT/TEST
TASKNO 3--COMMENT NO 3--COMMENT/TEST

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: What does table HEADER look like, and what sort of database is it?

Comment: SQL 2008 Database..Header is the name of one of the tables. Commentno is a title of a column

Comment: So what columns does the table have. Your 'diagrams' beginning TASKNO.... don't convey any sensible information to me.

Comment: Datbase has taskno, comment no, comment. Its basically just inserting Taskno(1) comment no(1) then(comment)...But I want to be able to add multiple comments under tasknumbers. So far its just adding comment numbers as 1,1,1,1,1. But I cant get it to add comment numbers like 1,2,3,4..

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not totally clear, but here goes:

If you want:

```
TaskId CommentId
1      1
1      2
2      3
1      4
3      5
```

This you can make CommentID an Identity comumn. This doesn't guarantee that the next will always by 1 greater than the previous; some things can happen (not often, but still) where it will loose a chunk of numbers and for instance got from 150 to 250 and miss out 151 to 249.

If you want this:

```
TaskId CommentId
1      1
1      2
2      1
1      3
3      1
```

Then you have to do this in the vba code where you insert the new comment: count the number already existing for the task and add 1 to get the CommentID for the new one.

Cheers -